# Highstocks Changing x axis tick from Feb DD. MMM to MMM DD

Tags: highcharts

I want to change the x axis tick format from 24. Feb to Feb 24. When M(Monthly) grouping is applied.

Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by "Monthly grouping is applied"? When the zoom level is set to "X months", or in general when the axis labels show labels in the format "24. Feb" (not including year or hours or anything)?

Comment: I am using highstocks grouping feature to group data. It is not really zooming, different from that.

Comment: But are you sure your data grouping affects the tick labels at all? I'm thinking it's more about how much data is shown on the xAxis (min and max dates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats) to set how different ranges for the x-axis affect the labels. It defaults to:

```
dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
    second: '%H:%M:%S',
    minute: '%H:%M',
    hour: '%H:%M',
    day: '%e. %b',
    week: '%e. %b',
    month: '%b \'%y',
    year: '%Y'
}
```

But you could alter the format for `week` to be "MMM DD." instead, like so ([JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a73AX/)):

```
dateTimeLabelFormats: {
    week: '%b %e.'
}
```

Not that if you want a leading zero for "DD" (e.g. "05") you have to use `%d` instead of `%e`. If you want it to apply to more ranges just add for `day`, `month`... as well.

The formatting codes that can be used are found in the [source code](http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js) (not in API, for some reason):

```
// Day
'a': langWeekdays[day].substr(0, 3), // Short weekday, like 'Mon'
'A': langWeekdays[day], // Long weekday, like 'Monday'
'd': pad(dayOfMonth), // Two digit day of the month, 01 to 31
'e': dayOfMonth, // Day of the month, 1 through 31

// Week (none implemented)
//'W': weekNumber(),

// Month
'b': lang.shortMonths[month], // Short month, like 'Jan'
'B': lang.months[month], // Long month, like 'January'
'm': pad(month + 1), // Two digit month number, 01 through 12

// Year
'y': fullYear.toString().substr(2, 2), // Two digits year, like 09 for 2009
'Y': fullYear, // Four digits year, like 2009

// Time
'H': pad(hours), // Two digits hours in 24h format, 00 through 23
'I': pad((hours % 12) || 12), // Two digits hours in 12h format, 00 through 11
'l': (hours % 12) || 12, // Hours in 12h format, 1 through 12
'M': pad(date[getMinutes]()), // Two digits minutes, 00 through 59
'p': hours < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM', // Upper case AM or PM
'P': hours < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm', // Lower case AM or PM
'S': pad(date.getSeconds()), // Two digits seconds, 00 through  59
'L': pad(mathRound(timestamp % 1000), 3) // Milliseconds (naming from Ruby)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can this also be used to represent quarters (3 months) as Q1'YY  Q2'YY ....

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [label formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) including [Highcharts.dateFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat)